# The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'

Tags: c#, namespaces, serial-port

I am working on developing a windows store app on my windows 8.1 system,64 bit (I need to deploy this app on my windows surface pro 3 tablet), technology being used is C#. I need to communicate through the RS-232 port. For this I am using the SerialPort class which falls under the namespace System.IO.Ports. But when I am including this in my C# code, I am getting the error -

"The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I have the windows SDK 8.0 installed. What could be the probable reason for this issue ? Is there any other was to communicate through the RS-232 port .

I am working on developing a windows store app on my windows 8.1 system,64 bit (I need to deploy this app on my windows surface pro 3 tablet), technology being used is C#. I need to communicate through the RS-232 port. For this I am using the SerialPort class which falls under the namespace System.IO.Ports. But when I am including this in my C# code, I am getting the error -

"The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I have the windows SDK 8.0 installed. What could be the probable reason for this issue ? Is there any other was to communicate through the RS-232 port .

Any pointer or suggested would be really helpful.

Here is the code -

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace App4
{
    public class Class2
    {
        private SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();
    }

    private void SerialPortInit()
        {

            comport.BaudRate = 115200;
            comport.DataBits = 8;
            comport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            comport.Parity = Parity.None;

        }
}
```

Google says that Serialport class is supported in dotNetFrameWork 4.5 (which is the one I am using) but still I am getting this error.

Regards, 
Shikha

Comment: you probably need to add a reference right click on your project in solution explorer and add reference

Comment: Windows Store apps are extremely restricted - it's entirely possible that the Windows Runtime doesn't provide the functionality you need.

Comment: See the comment here [http://stackoverflow.com/q/25710474/2655508](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25710474/2655508). Hans Passant knows about what he is talking.

Comment: I have already tried adding the reference. I have tried adding system.dll but getting this error -"A reference to System.dll could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system"

Comment: Do we have any other way to communicate through the RS-232 port other than serialport ?

Comment: And I am facing this issue on Windows 8.1 Enterprise and not windows RT

Comment: See for WinRT : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime

Answer (score 2):

Problem is the .net configuration.

Use the .NET 2.0 (not subset). Config:

Edit>ProjectSettings>Player>ApiCompatibilityLevel

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit->projectsettings->Player->APIcompetibilityLevel = .Net4.x
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is valid for VC++ but I think it is same or similar for C#.

Open Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line.
There is an "Additional Options" box below. Add following lines to there:

```
/FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Data.dll" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Drawing.dll" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.dll"
```

Pay attention to the path and .NET version before adding them.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue with .Net Core 3.1

[How to build cross-platform console apps with .NET Core](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/cross-platform-console-apps)

Add following to .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64;debian.8-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Then installed the package System.IO.Ports 4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Open the project as .Net Framework instead of .Net Core, this fixed my issue.
I was missing IO.Ports and My.Computer