# The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serial-port

In older versions of Unity (e.g. v5), I used to solve this issue by setting

> Edit > Project Settings > Player > **PC setting** (icon) > Other Settings > **API Compatibility Level**

from **.Net 2.0 Subset** to **.Net 2.0**

but in Unity 2018.3.2f1, this doesn't solve the issue. I also set the same setting to **.Net 4.x** but it didn't help.

**Note 1**: My build settings is set to **Android** platform but I need SerialPort class from System.IO.Ports namespace in order to read the serial port while running the game in the Unity Editor (PC). I have done this before with Unity 5.

**Note 2**: I cannot manually add a reference to the related assembly in the Visual Studio project made by Unity. The command is removed.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck at getting a solution if you asked this question on the [Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/) or on the [Unity Q&A Site](https://answers.unity.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround:

1. Switch the platform to PC: **File > Build Settings > (select) PC > 'Switch Platform'** button.
2. Go to **Visual Studio** and **Build > Build Solution**.
3. Switch back to Android: **File > Build Settings > (select) Android >'Switch Platform'** button.

By doing that, Unity adds the required assembly to 'Assembly-CSharp-Editor' project (which is related to running game inside Unity Editor).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit->projectsettings->Player->APIcompetibilityLevel = .Net4.x 
This worked for me.

check out this ->
[The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863021/the-type-or-namespace-name-ports-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-io/62298488#62298488)